# Multiple table filtering in Django DRF serializer or view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

What I am trying to do is retrieve records that are relevant to the current user.

I am using DRF JWT so the `user_id` is being stored in `sessionStorage` along with the JWT `token`. As I understand it, because JWT is being used, session authentication is not, so such things like `request.user` do not work. At least I could never get it working and was just told to store the `user_id` in `sessionStorage` with the JWT `token`. As such, if I want to retrieve records that are relevant to the current user, `sessionStorage.getItem('user_id')` needs to be passed to the API with `POST`. `GET` won't work since 1) `request.user` doesn't work and 2) can't send `sessionStorage.getItem('user_id')`.

So here are the models I am working with that I need to filter on with some example data:

```
-- Products table
prod_id | prod_name | active
----------------------------
3       | Widget1   | 0
10      | Widget2   | 1
11      | Widget3   | 1

-- Users table
user_id | username
------------------
10011   | joesmith

-- User_to_Products table
user_id | prod_id
-----------------
10011   | 3
10011   | 11
```

So what should be happening is the React FE sends the `sessionStorage.getItem('user_id')` to the DRF BE via `POST`, the DRF view has a `queryset` for the `User_to_Products`, it is serialized, and the `prod_id` and `prod_name` is sent back to the client so the `prod_name` can be rendered in the React FE.

That is the big picture and is happening for the most part. **However, if a `prod_id` is inactive (`0`) it should not be returned. Currently, I can filter on the items that are relevant to the `user_id`, but it is returning all `prod_id`. So I need to filter on `User_to_Products` and `Products`.**

This I am having trouble doing. I try to do something like:

```
user_id = request.data['user_id']
queryset = UserToProducts.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).filter(products__active=1)
```

Which would work in vanilla Django, but not in DRF. It thinks that `products__` is a field name in `User_to_Products` instead of thinking it is a table.

**So how do I do this correctly?**

Here is my code in its current state where it returns all `prod_id` even if inactive:

```
# ./views.py
class GetHomeAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = request.data['user_id']
        serializer = GetProductsSerializer(UserToProducts.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).prefetch_related('products'), many=True)            
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

```
# ./serializers.py
from .models import *

class GetProductsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
prod_name = CharField()
prod_id = IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model = UserToProducts
    fields = [
        'prod_id',
        'prod_name'
    ]
```

---

```
# ./models.py
User = get_user_model()

class Products(models.Model):
    prod_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserToProducts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prod_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Products'

class UserToProducts(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user', db_column='user_id', null=True)
    prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='products', db_column='prod_id', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.prod_id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'User_to_Products'
        unique_together = ('user_id', 'prod_id')
        ordering = ['-prod_id']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.user` should work with JWT authentication as well. You have to make sure you added its authentication class in REST_FRAMEWORK configuration dict like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        # ...
    ),
}
```

To render a field from a foreign key field, you can use the `source` attribute of the serializer field like this:

```
# ./serializers.py
from rest_framework.serializers import *
from .models import *

class GetProductsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    prod_name = CharField(source='prod.name')
    prod_id = IntegerField(source='prod.id')

    class Meta:
        model = UserToProducts
        fields = [
            'prod_id',
            'prod_name'
        ]
```

Also, the serializer you posted here does not make clear if you're using model fields instead of serializers fields. Make sure you using serializer fields in serializers.

About your models, you shouldn't append "_id" in foreign key fields, because Django abstract this for you. Under the hood it will create a positive integer field called {{the_field}}_id. You can use the foreign key fields as a model instance. This way:

```
class UserToProducts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='users', db_column='user_id', null=True)
    prod = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='products', db_column='prod_id', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.prod.id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'User_to_Products'
        unique_together = ('user', 'prod')
        ordering = ['-prod__id']
```

This way if you have a `UserToProducts` instance `user_to_products` and want to print its product name you can do `print(user_to_products.prod.name)`. Django will retrieve the Product in the database for you automatically.